# Error while trying to publish a test web app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment

I'm following the [very good tutorial of Tom Dykstra](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-production) about deployment of a web app to azure.
I almost got to publish, but when I try to press preview on the last tab of the Publish Web window, I get the following error:

> Invoke build failed due to exception 'Expected "$(_DeployOnBuild)" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "", in condition "'$(PipelineDeployPhaseAfterTargets)' == '' And $(_DeployOnBuild) ".  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets'

Trying to look for anything on google or in stackoverflow didn't find anything.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance,
Chaim